# Android says cannot resolve method 'getExternalFilesDir(null)'

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to try to write a file to external storage.

Other posts have recommended I do this using `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, but I get the message `Cannot resolve method 'getExternalFilesDir(null)'`.

```java
 public void makeFile() {
    try {
        String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "outputFile.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            String text = "Hello, world!";
            fos.write(text.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any way to get rid of this error.  Thanks in advance for any solutions to the problem.

Comment: `getExternalFilesDir ` method is from `Context` class, need a Context to call it from normal java class which is not sub-class of Context

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`getExternalFilesDir()` is method which requires `Context`. In Activity class you just need to call `getExternalFilesDir()`, but in other classes you need to call it with `Context`.

Like:

- `getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null)` in Fragment
- `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` in classes, where you pass `Context` as parameter
- `YourActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null);` when called in inner class of Activity

Comment: I tried passing Context as a parameter, but Android now says that the line `File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "outputFile.txt");` is "Not a Statement."

Comment: @OliviaWatkins Can you show your full code (class)?

Comment: I found the problem - I had a pair of brackets in the wrong place.  Now using `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` works; thanks.

Comment: Thanks. MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null) returns /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.k.myapplication/files

Comment: I'm such an idiot. Thanks for that simple and direct answer.

Comment: what if i want the foder in the root direactory not in my application because when app uninstall all daata also got deleted alternative any